# How do you access a local JSON file with an HTTP GET request in Angular 4?

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

I have a local JSON file that I'm trying to get access to through an HTTP GET request. I put it in `my-project/src/app/assets/accounts.json` and checked the JSON is good.

I perform the request from a service that is called by `ngOnInit()` - I have also tried without the 2nd parameter in the get

```ts
  public getFieldsFromFile() {
    const url = "assets/accounts.json";
    this.http.get(url, {responseType: "text"})
    .subscribe((data) => console.log(data));
  }
```

Unfortunately all I get in my `console.log` is this Error message

```ts
    HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 200, statusText: "OK", url: "http://users.local/assets/accounts.json", ok: false, …}
    error: {error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>) at XMLHttp…, text: "<!DOCTYPE html>↵<html>↵    <head>↵        <title>U…<script src="dist/js/users.js"></script>↵</html>↵"}
    headers: HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, lazyInit: ƒ}
    message: "Http failure during parsing for http://users.local/assets/accounts.json"
    name: "HttpErrorResponse"
    ok: false
    status: 200
    statusText: "OK"
    url: "http://users.local/assets/accounts.json"
```

If I expand, what I see is the HTML code of the `index.html`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Users</title>
        <base href="/" />
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/css/vendor.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/css/users.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <mv-users id="app-users">
            Loading...
        </mv-users>
    </body>
    <script src="dist/js/vendor.js"></script>
    <script src="dist/js/users.js"></script>
</html>
```

I understand this might be a router issue? Which is strange because I don't have any routes redirecting to `index.html`:

```ts
{
  path: "users",
  component: UsersComponent,
},
{ path: "**", redirectTo: "users" },
```

Comment: the redirection to the index.html is because it doesn't find the json file, you must add it to the angular config file to reach it

Comment: As long as it in the assets you can easily pull from it.
You can just use fetch() and receive the data you need.

Comment: Ive just noticed your error: message: "Http failure during parsing for http://users.local/assets/accounts.json"
how about remove that responseType?
looks like your main problem is that you try to parse none JSON string.

Answer (score 1):

There might be need to send header in request and also console the response with json conversion. Check the following...

```
public getFieldsFromFile() {
    const url = "assets/accounts.json";
    this.http.get(url, {responseType: "text"}, {headers:'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
    .subscribe((data) => console.log(data.json()));
}
```

You can do the syntax corrections.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by writing this .htaccess file in the json folder:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^(CONFIG|DATA).json$ - [NC,F,L]
```

and writing a simple get in my service

```
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
}

  public getSingleField(field) {
    this.http.get(`./src/app/assets/${field}.json`);
}
```